# How to search attributes of dir(object) in REPL of Python3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

In using dir(object) to list attributes for example

```
>>>dir(os)
['CLD_CONTINUED', 'CLD_DUMPED', 'CLD_EXITED', 'CLD_TRAPPED', 'DirEntry', 'EX_CANTCREAT', 'EX_CONFIG', 'EX_DATAERR', 'EX_IOERR', 'EX_NOHOST', 'EX_NOINPUT', 'EX_NOPERM', 'EX_NOUSER', 'EX_OK', 'EX_OSERR', 'EX_OSFILE', 'EX_PROTOCOL', 'EX_SOFTWARE', 'EX_TEMPFAIL', 'EX_UNAVAILABLE', 'EX_USAGE', 'F_LOCK', 'F_OK', 'F_TEST', 'F_TLOCK', 'F_ULOCK', 'MutableMapping', 'NGROUPS_MAX', 'O_ACCMODE', 'O_APPEND', 'O_ASYNC', 'O_CLOEXEC', 'O_CREAT', 'O_DIRECTORY', 'O_DSYNC', 'O_EXCL', 'O_EXLOCK', 'O_NDELAY', 'O_NOCTTY', 'O_NOFOLLOW',...
```

Is there a way to search the output, for example if I already know the method has "ch" in it?

Comment: Currently I am just using the IDLE search function.

Comment: or ```'chdir' in dir(os)```